# Visualising Keras CNN final trained filters at each layer

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

the same question was asked by someone :[visualize learned filters in keras cnn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49662379/visualize-learned-filters-in-keras-cnn). But it has no answers, so I asked it again.
I know that Keras has default filters at each layer which are then modified and adjusted. After all modification, I want to see how these filters (32 or 64 or any number) look. I know that when prediction of new image happens, these filters are applied one-by-one to predict the image. But how these TRAINED filters look? I went  through several blogs and posts which titles "Visualise keras filters" or so. But I don't know how to apply them in my case. I have trained a keras CNN  model and save it to .hdf5 file. Please help!. I want to see all filters at each layer.

Comment: How is your case different from the blog posts you mention? Its just a matter of getting a convolutional layer weights (with the get_weights function) and visualize them.

Comment: By "visualising" I mean "plotting them as images". Can you suggest a link for that? Or can you tell me how can I use https://github.com/jacobgil/keras-filter-visualization in my case. I have a .hdf5 file and how should I use the viz.py given in the Readme.md file at the above link

Comment: Moreover what I understand by IMG in viz.py usage, it is that it uses a image and project the filters on it and displays the image. Right? But I want to see the filters, not the image after projection of filters on it

Comment: The way my case differs is that I want to see the filters and not the image after effects of filter on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite easy to do:

```
import numpy as np
model = load_model('your_model.hdf5')

#Select a convolutional layer
layer = model.layers[1]

#Get weights
kernels, biases = layer.get_weights()

#Normalize kernels into [0, 1] range for proper visualization
kernels = (kernels - np.min(kernels, axis=3)) / (np.max(kernels, axis=3) - np.min(kernels, axis=3))

#Weights are usually (width, height, channels, num_filters)
#Save weight images
import cv2

for i in range(kernels.shape[3]):
    filter = kernels[:, :, :, i]
    cv2.imwrite('filter-{}.png'.format(i), filter)
```

With this code you will get a bunch of PNG files, one for each filter. You can do other kinds of visualizations like using matplotlib.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot it worked!!! Great. Only I used model.layers[0] for convolutional layer. because it gave empty results for layer[1] . I think it is because it considers that as maxpooling layer.

Comment: Just a doubt , it gave 64 3x3 px images but all black images. I dont know whether I am right, but I feel filters should vary because they produce results on image and if they are all same they will produce same results.

Comment: @Yusuf Added normalization to correctly show the filters.

Comment: I added the code as follows `for i in range(kernels.shape[3]):
    kernels[:,:,:,i] = (kernels[:,:,:,i] - np.min(kernels, axis=3)) / np.max(kernels, axis=3) - np.min(kernels, axis=3)` after it gave error as `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,3,3,64) (3,3,3) `. It successfully converted to 0-1 values. I check that by `print(filter)` . However I feel the contrast may not be visible clearly since I can still see all black images. I cannot add images here else I would have shown it to you. If it should be visible then please help me . Else thanks for the help

Comment: Try multiplying the filters by 255

Comment: Amazingly great! Now I can see 64 different 3x3px images having different colours for each pixel. What I learned during CNN tutorials was that each filter represents one feature of the image and at end all filters do a sort of collective effort in detecting/identifying the image. So how these filters with random colours represent which feature of my image. for example how these 3x3 image represent a whiskers in identifying the cat in image? I am asking this because I would be asked during presentation by my external examiner about the same?