# Visualizing deep layer filters in Keras CNN

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

My question is simple. I want to visualize what filters are used in ConvNet in deep layers to extract the features predicting the final model. By visualize I mean to save it in .png format like filters shown in final layer of https://s3-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/av-blog-media/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/cnn_filters.png , we can actually see a car in final layer filters

I can visualise the filters of first convolutional layer by help provided from my own question [Visualising Keras CNN final trained filters at each layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54959454/visualising-keras-cnn-final-trained-filters-at-each-layer) but that shows only to visualise for first layer. First layer filters look like some random coloured 3x3 pixel images. But I want to see the final layer filters like the car filter in the first link.

First layer filters look like some random coloured 3x3 pixel images. But I want to see the final layer filters like the car filter in the first link.
Even the article of car filter https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/03/essentials-of-deep-learning-visualizing-convolutional-neural-networks/ has code for only first layer

Answer (score 2):

You can adress the weights of the different layers by:

```py
w = model.layers[i].get_weights()[0][:,:,:,:]
```

where `i` is the number of your layer.

In case of the picture in the link I am not sure if it is actually the weights or maybe the activation map which is shown. You could get that one by:

```py
from keras import backend as K

get_output = K.function([model.layers[0].input],[cnn.layers[i].output])
output_normal = get_output([X])[0][m]
```

where `m` is the number of a certain image in `X` as input.

Comment: `a = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]` gives `a` of size `(3,3,3,32)` so I think your first code should be `w = model.layers[i].get_weights()[0][:,:,:,0]` . By this way I could save 32 images of filters as first layer has 32 filters. But the code did not worked for second layer.

Comment: `a = model.layers[2].get_weights()[0]` gives `a` of size `(3,3,32,16)` . I have 16 filters in my second conv layer.

Comment: Yes you're right. The indices are: 1. kernel width, 2. kernel height, 3. number of channels, 4. number of filters. You would adress all channels of the first filter in your second layer by: ```w = model.layers[1].get_weights()[0][:,:,:,0]```

Comment: any suggestions for finding the second layer filters?

Comment: Yes, try: ```w = model.layers[1].get_weights()[0][:,:,:,0]```. The numeration of your layers starts at 0. So your second layer is ```layer[1]```

Comment: For first layer `w = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0][:,:,:,0]` gave `w` as of size `(3,3,3)` so I could save it as image of 3 channels. But for second layer `w = model.layers[2].get_weights()[0][:,:,:,0]` gave `w` as of size `(3,3,32)` so I could as  save it as image. see my second comment

Comment: I should layers[2] because second layer was max pooling and by second layer I meant second conv layer

Comment: Yes, if you apply 32 filters in your first layer you'll get 32 activationmaps/channels into your second layer. You could plot each of them as a separate greyscale picture but of course not as one RGB picture.

Comment: Yeah plotting them as grayscale will solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @SebastianDengler I am interested in the comment about not being able to do so in a single RGB picture. Is it possible to apply each kernel model.layers[i].get_weights()[0][:,:,:,k] to each channel of an RGB (or even higher channel) image and then display that?  I mean I know I *can*, but just not sure if this is a correct thought.

Comment: Puh, I'll not claim that I can remember this nearly 4 year old question, however I'll say the following: Of course you can split let's say 12 kernels into 4 RGB pictures or visualise each as grayscale image. However, the meaning behind behind each kernel becomes lost. Whereas if you had only three kernels you might say that the model seems to focus on a certain red region in your picture or a certain blue area. To me it's a bit like string theory. You can calculate in 10 dimensions and the math checks out, however you cannot visually explain it.

Answer (score 2):

The Python library [keras-vis](https://github.com/raghakot/keras-vis) is a great tool for visualizing CNNs. It can generate conv filter visualizations, dense layer visualizations, and attention maps. The latest release is quite old (and a little bit buggy), so I recommend installing from `master`:

```sh
pip install git+https://github.com/raghakot/keras-vis.git
```

Comment: Hey the library seems to solve my problem but the documentation links seems to be broken of attention maps, convnet filter visualisation and dense layer visualisations

Comment: @Yusuf you can check out the [examples directory](https://github.com/raghakot/keras-vis/tree/master/examples), where you can find activation maximization examples for `mnist` and `vggnet`. Also, take a look at the [docs for activation maximization](https://raghakot.github.io/keras-vis/visualizations/activation_maximization/).

Comment: i know it sounds weird but what images of various numbers in cell number 26 in https://github.com/raghakot/keras-vis/blob/master/examples/mnist/activation_maximization.ipynb tells about the network. It just the blurred images of input image. Unlike the first link in my question clearly shows the car in final layer filters. If i have some misconceptions please make me cleared on it.

Comment: Also if you see the images under `dense layer visualisation` at https://github.com/raghakot/keras-vis it shows clearly the bird images.

Comment: @Yusuf, as mentioned in the [docs](https://raghakot.github.io/keras-vis/visualizations/activation_maximization/), "The idea behind activation maximization is [to] generate an input image that maximizes the filter output activations." It's an effective method for visualization. It's not the same as simply plotting weights.

Comment: the doc link was unavailable few moments ago so I could not see that. So I have a better understanding now.

Comment: Suppose I have a filter 3x3 and image of 28x28. The filters look uninterpretable  just random colours for 9 pixels. If I convoled that filter with input image and the areas on image that highly activates with filter means that the filter represents that portion/pattern/part  of the image. This is what a heatmap does basically.

Comment: The only doubt I have now is that the dense layer images I mentioned earlier is actually a `filter` or a `heatmap of a filter on image`. If it is a filter how can I actually see that for my model saved as .h5 file. I could not find the code for it on the keras-viz PS-I could see the 3x3 filters of conv layer which does clearly show any input pattern

Comment: @Yusuf, if you have saved the whole model (`model.save`), you just need to load it (`keras.models.load_model`). But if you have only saved the weights (`model.save_weights`) you need to compile the same model and then load the weights (`model.load_weights`).

Comment: Hi @Soroush, I have a question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57768405/keras-vis-for-the-saliency-charts-shall-we-use-softmax-or-linear-activation